# Using Owner Handle in WPF window Show method

Tags: c#, wpf

In Winforms we have Show(IWin32Window owner) method to Show a form based on the owner handle passed to the Show method.

I want to have similar behavior in WPF Window. But WPF window doesn't have Show method which accepts an owner handle.

Another alternative which I found is by setting window.Owner to the owner window and then use window.Show(). But by doing this we can assign only a WPF window as the owner. 
In my case the owner can be a winform or a WPF window. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Setting the [`Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property of the window is the correct way of creating a relationship between two WPF windows (as per Remarks section of the [`Window.Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property MSDN page).

However, if you want to set the owner to a Winforms `Form`, you have to use [`WindowInteropHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) class:

```
WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow);
helper.Owner = form.Handle;
```